# How can I use an int in __asm__?

Tags: c, assembly

I want to use an char variable in c and add it to the assembly code.

```
char c = 'X';
__asm__ __volatile__("movb '"c"', %ah\n");
```

but when I use it it says a string literal is expected. How do I cast it?
Also I am using this code to make my own os so there will be no standard libraries.

Comment: You have to use an an inputconstraint to pass variable `c` into the template. You'd need an unput constraint to transfer the value from ah to some variable.

Comment: You need extended asm, read [this](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

Comment: The detailed docs for gcc's `asm` are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  If your asm will not be changing the value of `c`, then it should get passed as an InputOperand.

Comment: What would I put in the assembly template part?

Comment: From the docs: you should *use the (zero-based) position of the operand in the list of operands in the assembler template.*  So if you only have 1 input (and 0 output) params, you would refer to it as `%0`.  Note that just moving `c` into `ah` makes no sense.  Whatever you think you are trying to do (setting up to call an interrupt?), this probably isn't going to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline assembler line has two problems:

1) You are using AT&T syntax. In AT&T syntax constant values use a `$`:

```
mov $'c', %ah
```

As far as I know a `%` must be written as `%%` when using inline assembly - similar to `printf()`. So a correct program would look like this:

```
#define c "X"
__asm__ __volatile__("movb $'" c "', %%ah\n");
```

2) This will only work when `c` is a string constant.

You'll have to use inline assembler operands if you want to use parameters. If `c` is a constant the following will work:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("movb %0, %%ah\n"::"i" (c));
```

This will generate the instruction `movb $'x', %ah` however this will only work if the compiler optimization is on so the compiler knows that `c` has the value `'x'` here.

If `c` is really a variable (which can change its value) or the compiler cannot figure out that `c` has a constant value you'll have to do something like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("movb %0, %%ah\n"::"m" (c));
```

This will result in an instruction like `movb 7(%rsp), %ah` (or `movb 3(%esp), %ah` in the case of 32-bit code).

Searching for information about inline assembly in the internet I found the following page containing more information:

https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: you leave off something important, this is extremely bad to modify a register without telling the compiler. you turn optimizations on andthis type of code has a good chance of failing if the compiler assumes _EAX_ was not changed it may rely on the value being the same before and after the template.

Comment: There Is this error when using your last approach: number of operands mismatch for mov

Comment: You can compile C code to assembly code. Then you can see what the compiler really made out of the inline assembly code.

Comment: You can use a `"rmi"(c)` constraint to give the compiler the option of choosing any register.  Or even better, ask the compiler to put the variable in AH for you: `register char c asm("ah")` should work, I think.  (There isn't a constraint for AH specifically.  There's `"a"`, which asks for `al/ax/eax/rax` depending on width, but not AFAIK one for AH.  You could ask for `c<<8` in EAX, though.)  `mov` as the first instruction of an asm statement is almost always doing it wrong; use constraints to avoid redundant instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes "r" would result in an instruction like `movb %eax, %al` which will not work.

Comment: Did you try it?  `c` is a `char`, so it will be in an 8-bit register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry. Did not see the "`(c)`" in your post.

Comment: If you want to skip the variable and use a numeric literal, `"rmi"( (int8_t) 'X')` works, if `'X'` isn't already of `char` type (I forget).